# SQL Server storing wildcards in data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I was shown a table in SQL Server that included `%` wildcards in the actual table data. ie:

```
Column1 : Column2 : Column3
1        %         2
3        %         %
```

This allowed the developer to run `like` queries on this data and the underlying data would also evaluate as a secondary pattern match.

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Column1 LIKE '123'` would return no records.

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Column2 LIKE '123'` would return all records.

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Column3 LIKE '2'` would return all records.

`SELECT * FROM tble WHERE Column3 LIKE '123'` would return only the last record.

I have looked everywhere to find out how this is possible, but I can only find a bunch of information on `like` queries where the wildcard is in the query itself, not in the data.

1. What is this voodoo called and where can I find documentation?
2. Do other databases support it?
3. Does this feature exist in an search indexes (SOLR or ElasticSearch) without writing extra code?

**UPDATE**
So, it was not so much voodoo as my poor memory. Inverting the the `like` makes much more sense.
`SELECT * FROM tble WHERE '123' LIKE Column1`

Comment: I tried your examples in SQL Server and MySQL too. They don't work as you say... at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your examples inverted.

You need to use

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '123' LIKE Column1
```

etc.

To give your desired results ([demo](http://rextester.com/FCI99352))

There is no particular "voodoo". `LIKE` takes a string with a match expression on the left hand side and a string with a pattern on the right hand side and doesn't care if either or both strings come from a column or not. So the documentation you need is just the docs for [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

It will behave this way in all DBMSs I imagine.

But whilst this developer may have found it convenient all such queries will result in a table scan rather than being able to locate the desired rows potentially more efficiently with seeks.

Comment: Oh yeah. This makes sense to me. Phew... I thought I was going crazy. I even thought SQL Server had this "inverted LIKE" feature... who knows.

Comment: I am suspicious that the reverse `like` is what the OP really intends.  The OP explicitly mentions a pattern match, suggesting (to me at least) that the like pattern in the question could have wildcards.

Comment: @GordonLinoff They **do** have a pattern match. The patterns with wildcards (in this case just `%`) are  stored in the table. How else would `WHERE '123' LIKE Column2` return the rows where the value in `Column2` is `%`?

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I was thinking the user input might be something like `'12%'`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the "voodoo" is called `or`:

```
WHERE Column1 LIKE '123' OR Column1 = '%'
```

`OR` is a pretty common construct across languages, so I would expect other systems, such as ElasticSearch, to support it as well.

[Here](http://rextester.com/XLIAV82753) is a rextester showing that the results are correct.

As I mentioned in a comment.  I specifically chose this solution because the OP mentioned a "pattern match", leading me to think that the fixed pattern could have wildcards.  The question is a bit ambiguous on that point, and the reverse `like` may be what the OP has in mind.  That is just not how I read the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I fail to see the relationship between your answer and the question. How did you get to it?

Comment: @Impaler . . . I read the question.  Looked at the conditions and validated that this would satisfy the four conditions.  It appears to be exactly what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Impaler . . . You should check the code out in the Rex Tester.  The downvotes are rather offensive, on a solution that works and is quite concise.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't understand this alternative solution. Upvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you reverse the order of the operands to `LIKE`:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE '123' LIKE Column2` would return all records.

See [this demo](http://rextester.com/discussion/RJXZW70456/sql-server-storing-wildcards-in-data)

Comment: Ninja'd by Martin. Oh well.